# How to add a launchpad repository to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, ppa, launchpad

There is a project that I want to install on my host:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libguestfs-tools/1:1.28.12-1ubuntu2

How to figure out information for **add-apt-repository** command using the project description given in the mentioned page ?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a PPA for that, the package you are mentioning is part of the official Ubuntu repositories, more precisely the `universe` repository for Xenial.

This can be verified using the command `apt policy libguestfs-tools`, which should directly display you that package from the `xenial/universe` repo as installation candidate.

Installing it then is as simple as

```
sudo apt install libguestfs-tools
```

You know that a package on Launchpad is part of the official Ubuntu repositories if the author (see the big headline right at the top of the page, with the icon) is "Ubuntu" and not any Launchpad user name. The URL starts with `/ubuntu` as well for packages from the official repos.

---

As you specified an older version in your link, which got updated and is no longer existing in the official repositories, you have no real way of still getting that old version from any repository or PPA.

The Ubuntu repos do not keep old replaced versions of packages around and there also is no Launchpad PPA where they get automatically available. You can download the package directly from the link given on that site, but there will be no real PPA where you get that old version from unless any user manually creates it and rebuilds that old version there themselves.

Comment: Yes, I know that, thanks. But the standart repository contains the latest version of **libguetsfs-tools** which issue some problems with KVM. That why I decided to downgrade to mentioned version. That version exists in PPA only.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the version you specified. Well, the Ubuntu repos do not keep old replaced versions of packages around and there also is no Launchpad PPA where they get automatically available. You can download the package directly from the link given on that site, but there will be no real PPA where you get that old version from unless any user manually creates it and rebuilds that old version there themselves.